# Minimal polynomial with repeated factors over an algebraically closed field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $V$ be a vector space over $k$ and let $T: V \to V$ be any linear transformation. I can't think of an example when the minimal polynomial of $T$ will ever have repeated factors.

But such an example must exist since not every linear transformation is diagonaliazable.

Anyway, what is an example of a linear transformation on $V$ such that the minimal polynomial has repeated factors?

Comment: The zero mapping is such an example.

Comment: @user2097 : $m(\lambda)=\lambda$ is the minimal polynomial of the $0$ mapping.

Comment: @TrialAndError Oh, thank you, this was a stupid comment I posted. I had in mind a characteristic polynomial actually...

Answer (score 1):

The transformation
$$
T = \left[ \begin{array}{cc)}
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0  \end{array}\right]$$
has minimal polynomial $x^{2}$.

PS: If the dimension is finite, you can look for Jordan Block (Jordan Canonical form).

Comment: For the minimal polynomial to make sense, the dimension has to be finite.